# How to properly align math cases and make them less compact?

Tags: amsmath, cases

I have the following code that produces this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
F(X) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
     0, & \text{if } x < 0\\
    \frac{8}{100}, & \text{if } 0\leq x < 0.5\\
    \frac{5}{100}, & \text{if } 0.5\leq x< 3.5\\
    \frac{20}{100}, & \text{if } 3.5\leq x < 4.5\\
    \frac{53}{100}, & \text{if } 4.5 \leq x\\
    1, & \text{if }  x > 4.5
    \end{array}\right\} 
\]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, there are many problems with the appearance of these cases. The fractions on the left are very near to each other which makes them hard to read,  it looks like the 0 starts a bit more to the left than the others and finally, the ***if*** statements are not properly aligned. How could I fix this?

Comment: \\ -> \\[1ex] or so?

Comment: @JouleV Replacing '\\'  with '\\\[1ex]' indeed solve the problem of them being compact. Thanks!

Comment: However, why don't you use `cases` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would always use a `cases` environment for something like this. Well, actually, I would use a `cases*` environment from the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package so that the `\text{...}` commands are not needed. I'd also omit he righthand brace and just write:

[image]

If you really do want the right-hand brace then you can add it with with the usual `\left.  ... \right\}` construct to produce:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
F(X) =   \begin{cases*}
     0, & if $ x < 0$,\\
    \frac{8}{100}, & if $0\leq x < 0.5$,\\
    \frac{5}{100}, & if $0.5\leq x< 3.5$,\\
    \frac{20}{100},& if $3.5\leq x < 4.5$,\\
    \frac{53}{100},& if $4.5 \leq x$,\\
    1,             & if $x > 4.5$.
  \end{cases*}
\]

\[
F(X) = \left.  \begin{cases*}
     0, & if $ x < 0$\\
    \frac{8}{100}, & if $0\leq x < 0.5$\\
    \frac{5}{100}, & if $0.5\leq x< 3.5$\\
    \frac{20}{100},& if $3.5\leq x < 4.5$\\
    \frac{53}{100},& if $4.5 \leq x$\\
    1,             & if $x > 4.5$
  \end{cases*}\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, I lose you by 3 seconds :))) +1 and will delete my answer

Comment: @JouleV You have been very helpful. You shouldn't have deleted your answer. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @JouleV Sorry! It's viscous here sometimes! You should keep your post too though:)

Comment: @Doesitmatter Well, it is a rule here, that if two answer are duplicates, the later needs deletion. Btw, Andrew's answer contains more information than mine.

Comment: @JouleV Well, except that your post is *not* actually a duplicate since your using `cases` - and also not everyone follows this rule!